# MVC - Passing an object and a string in @Html.ActionLink call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have the following foreach that creates rows in a table.

_Summary.cshtml

```
@model KpiSummaryViewModel

...
@foreach (TimeIntervalAndStatus error in Model.MergedErrorTimeIntervals)
   {
      <tr>
         <td style="font-size: small" class="td downTimes">@error.TimeStart</td>
         <td style="font-size: small" class="td downTimes">@error.TimeEnd</td>
         <td style="font-size: small" class="td downTimes">@(error.TimeEnd - 
         error.TimeStart)</td>
         <td style="font-size: small" class="td downTimes">
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index", "Details", error, null)
         </td>
      </tr>
   }
```

When I click the ActionLink above, I want to pass error but also KpiSummaryViewModel.SummaryInformation.Name to the Details Controller.

My DetailsController

```
public class DetailsController : Controller
{
   private TimeIntervalAndStatus _error;
   // GET: Details
   public ActionResult Index(TimeIntervalAndStatus error)
    {
        var detailsViewModel = new DetailsViewModel
        {
            QueryStartDate = error.TimeStart,
            QueryEndDate = error.TimeEnd
        };
        return View(detailsViewModel);
    }
}
```

My DetailsViewModel

```
public class DetailViewModel
{
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")]
   public DateTime QueryStartDate { get; set; }

   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")]
   public DateTime QueryEndDate { get; set; }

   public TimeSpan DetailDownTimeDuration { get; set; }
}
```

My Details.cshtml

```
@model Foo.Models.DetailViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Down-time details</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what I need is access to the error object the Html.ActionLink passes so i can set the fields on the DetailsViewModel to those TimeStart, TimeEnd and Duration. I will then use this information to retrieve other information. This part works, but I also need access to the @Model.SummaryInformation.Name. So I want to pass two things.

I don't want to add the Name to the TimeIntervalAndStatus as it doesn't make sense for that object to have the summary Name.

Perhaps I shouldn't be using an @Html.ActionLink, is there a better way to do this?

I have tried making my ActionLink this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index", "Details", new { error, kpiName = Model.SummaryInformation.Name}, null)
```

Then my controller method becomes

```
public ActionResult Index(TimeIntervalAndStatus error, string kpiName)
{

}
```

But then error is always null.

Comment: What html generate after u try `new {error, kpiName= Model....}`

Comment: I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object, because error is null.

Comment: The url looks like this `http://localhost:54816/Details?error=Foo.Models.TimeIntervalAndStatus&kpiName=APS`

Comment: try this and check url `new {TimeIntervalAndStatus  = { TimeStart =  error.TimeStart , TimeEnd = error.TimeEnd} , kpiName = Model.SummaryInformation.Name }`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. Now error is not null. But it has only the default values for DateTime. So TimeStart and TimeEnd are both {01/01/0001 00:00:00}. The kpiName is correct.

Comment: change `TimeInternvalAndStatus` to `error`

Comment: error = null again :( '@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index", "Details", new { error = new TimeIntervalAndStatus() { TimeStart = error.TimeStart, TimeEnd = error.TimeEnd}, kpiName = Model.SummaryInformation.Name}, null)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141429/discussion-between-umair-anwaar-and-stuart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass error Id and not error object in action link as it generates a Url. So change your View as

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index", "Details", new { errorId = error.Id, kpiName = Model.SummaryInformation.Name}, null)
```

And in your controller you can get related error object in action method using error id

```
public ActionResult Index(int errorId, string kpiName)
{
    // get error object using error id
}
```

Hope that solves your problem!

Comment: Makes sense. And if errorId approach does not work you should flatten parameters and update view model to contain the `Name` property.

Comment: I don't have an id on error. In my other viewModel, I receive a list of times and TimeIntervalAndStatus is those times merged together to remove overlapping times. But really, all i need is kpiName, TimeStart and TimeEnd.

Comment: @Stuart, even in that case you don't need to build and pass object, you can pass dates as other parameters. i.e. new { startDate = error.TimeStart, endDate = error.TimeEnd, kpiName = Model.SummaryInformation.Name }. Add those as your action method parameters and build object there.

Comment: Yes, making it 3 parameters. Two DateTime and a string fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be doing this ok. However your link should read

@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index", "Details", new { error = error, kpiName = Model.SummaryInformation.Name}, null)

The error = error is needed to assign the error value (in your for loop) to enable your controller to receive it.